# Is my file/class naming convention OK for codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am starting a new project and want things to be done right:

Controller:

file name: routemanagerdashboard.php
class name: RouteManagerDashboard

Views:
file name: routemanagerdashboard_dashboard.php

Model: 
file name: routemanagerdashboard_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, but `routemanagerdashboard` seems a bit verbose, you may consider coming up with something shorter. If you like the controller class name but hate the long urls, you can always use a [route](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to get around it.

Since we're dealing with PHP, case sensitivity is not an issue, so your controller class name is fine, just as long as it matches the characters in it's file name. Just stick to lowercase file names.

Your model name is using the common CI convention, but be aware that when loading the model you may use the second parameter to alias the class name for easier use. Example:

```
$this->load->model('routemanagerdashboard_model', 'r_model');
$this->r_model->get_something(); // A little easier to work with
```

On views: It's probably better to create a subdirectory for all views that are directly related to the controller. You are probably going to need more than just one view file per controller. You will see your `/views` folder become unmaintainable if you put all view files directly in the root of it. I suggest you use sub directories and short meaningful file names, perhaps matching the name of the controller method you intend to load them in. Example:

```
// file = /views/routemanager/dashboard.php
$this->load->view('routemanager/dashboard');
```

So, yes - you're Doing it Right for the most part, but coming up with shorter names if possible, and organizing your view files into subdirectories will probably be a good idea.

Comment: sir, I am stuck with this same naming convention problem. I have my home.PHP default controller. I have given "Home" as the class name. Now the Problem is I have Linux hosting so it shows the 404 error.  so what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

These naming conventions are perfectly fine.  Although there are some conventions you must follow, what you name your files/classes mostly comes down to personal preference.  After working with CodeIgniter for a couple years I've settled on the following naming conventions for my files.

**Controllers:** companies.php (plural file and class name)

**Models:** company_model.php (singular of the table it corresponds to)

**Views:** companies/method_name.php (all views for the controller go into a folder for views in that class)

I always make my database table names plural and have a one-to-one relationship between my models and tables.  Controllers usually have a corresponding table and model, but not always.  I also use a [base model](http://chris-schmitz.com/codeigniter-base-model/) which removes a lot of the tedium of setting up a new model for every table which fits into this setup very well and is probably a big reason that I stick pretty strictly to it.

Comment: I am having question regarding "one-to-one relationship between models and tables", where should I place my code which contains join to another table(s)?